# C# Launching Yodlee FastLink

Tags: model-view-controller, yodlee

I'm doing a project to launch yodlee fastlink. I was able to get the token and userSession and trying the below codes. I'm only getting "Cannot POST resource". I'm trying to find a more detailed/simpler documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <form action="https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver" method="post" name="rsessionPost" id="rsessionPost" target="yodleeIframe">
        <input style="visibility: hidden" type="text" name="rsession" placeholder="rsession" value="08312016_0:149676f79ace306255a2c7827f9db590ccabd7350ad5d952f31fc503675bba9ec522728c213a9e5c3e98bd8ceff795c88f9a6f80040a68ce325ae54759f6e504" id="rsession" /><br />
        <input style="visibility: hidden" type="text" name="app" placeholder="FinappId" value="10003600" id="finappId" /><br />
        <input style="visibility: hidden" type="text" name="redirectReq" placeholder="true/false" value="true" /><br />
        <input style="visibility: hidden" type="text" name="token" placeholder="token" value="e59f51a169f52925cd715a945630686e59667d2d1fae511fd50b4e292a8e7342" id="token" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a forward slash '/' missing at the end of the URL.
Please put it there and submit the form you should be able to access Fastlink.

"https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/"